# how to compare two databases in matlab

Tags: database, matlab, compare

I have two database in excel being extracted not in matlab. How can I compare them within matlab? Is the right way, storing them in a structure ? how I can find the similarities and differences?

- Each database has 4 columns, and database has around 400 rows of data.

Comment: Extarct it as a matrices to matlab and use `isequal`, for get true/false, or substruct one from another to get the differences.

Comment: But I have been given the databases, and I should compare them in matlab. So, saving the whole database in matlab through structure is the efficient way?

Comment: @Biju Assuming they are numeric, and the column name comparison is not interesting, you can just store them in a matrix. This should be more easy to handle than a struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the structure, you could create a `struct` for each database where each fieldname is equal to a column name.

- In this case one can use `visdiff`.

However if you are going to compare a lot of numbers this is not practical.

- To confirm that they are equal, one can use something like `isequal`
- To see how they are different, `plot` them or plot the `difference` of them.
- To see whether the data behaves differently calculate some basic statistics like `max`, `min`, `mean`, `std`, you may also be interested in the correlation between columns of the two  datasets.